# How can I search within a specific website with PHP and the Google API?

Tags: php, api

How can I search within a specific website with PHP and the Google API? When I search for a keyword, I want the result from `website1.com` AND `website2.com` AND `website3.com`. For example:

```
<input name="search" value="keyword"> 
<input name="as_site" value="site1.com"> 
<input name="as_site" value="site2.com">
<input name="as_site" value="site3.com">
```

The result should be returned from these three websites only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: The Google Web Search API has been officially deprecated as of November 1, 2010. It >will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but the number of requests you may make >per day will be limited. Therefore, we encourage you to move to the new Custom Search API.

According to your form and assuming that the keyword field is named `keyword` this sample code is assuming you have only one site to search you can customize it to include many.
Assuming that the site input is named `site`

```
// The request also includes the userip parameter which provides the end
// user's IP address. Doing so will help distinguish this legitimate
// server-side traffic from traffic which doesn't come from an end-user.
$query = $_POST['keyword'];
$site = $_POST['site'];
$url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&"
    . "q={$query}+Site:{$site}&userip=USERS-IP-ADDRESS";

// sendRequest
// note how referer is set manually
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, /* Enter the URL of your site here */);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// now, process the JSON string
$json = json_decode($body);
// now have some fun with the results...
```